# Homogeneous 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question comes from Schaums Calculus, CH59 Q18 which has had me confused for a couple of days now.

Solve:
$$
{dy \over dx} + y = xy^2
$$

I understand that this is a non-linear first order ode, where a substitution of $z=y^{-n}$ gives:

$$
{dz\over dx} - z = -x
$$

So in this case $P(x) = -1$ and so the integrating factor, $u = e^{-x}$ and hence we try to solve:

$$
e^{-x}{dz \over dx} - ze^{-x} = -xe^{-x}
$$

Schaums suggests (and this is the bit where I am lost), that this is just:

$$
e^{-x} dx - ze^{-x} dx= -xe^{-x} dx
$$

Implying that all dx's cancel:

$$
ze^{-x}= xe^{-x} + e^{-x} + C
$$
$$
{1 \over y} = 1 + Ce^x
$$

However I am missing something because to me this looks like:

$$
e^{-x} dz - ze^{-x} dx= -xe^{-x} dx
$$

Where one term is the integral wrt z and the other 2 wrt x, however Schaum's method looks rather elegant but and I don't quite understand how to replicate it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=xy^2$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{y}=x\text{ , dividing by $y^2$}$$

Now put , $-\frac{1}{y}=z$. Then , $\frac{dz}{dx}-z=x$

So, I.F.$=e^{-x}$. So solution is  $z.e^{-x}=\int xe^{-x}\,dx+C=-e^{-x}(x+1)+C$.

i.e. $-\frac{y}{x}e^{-x}=-e^{-x}(x+1)+C\implies \frac{y}{x}=x+1-Ce^x$

Comment: How did you get from ${dz\over dx} −z=x$ to $$z.e^ {−x} = \int xe ^{−x} dx+C$$

Comment: Do you know what is I.F. ?Do you know how can solve a D.E.from I.F. ?

Comment: As I understand it, you multiply each term by the I.F and then re-arrange so that M(x) and N(x) can be solved exactly. I believe I am confused by Schaum's notation.

Comment: Do you want to solve it by exact form $M\,dx+N\,dy$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You properly arrived at $$e^{-x}{dz \over dx} - ze^{-x} = -xe^{-x}$$ (by the way, I do not understand how you went from this line to the next). Divide each term by $e^{-x}$ to get  $${dz \over dx} - z = -x$$ which looks to be simple.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks Claude, although I have edited my question as it wasn't explicit enough.